# Finding the taylor series of a function given as an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the taylor series of the function $$g(x)=\int^x_0 e^{t^3}dt$$

My first attempt was to use the 'fundamental theorem of calculus' to get :

$$g'(x)= e^{t^3}$$

And then somehow utilize that $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^∞\frac {x^n}{n!} $$

Resulting in $$g'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^∞\frac {{({t^3})}^n}{n!} $$

I feel this is getting further from the answer by the line. Can this be salvaged or is a different approach needed?

Comment: Not sure whether this is a misunderstanding or a typo: $g'(x)\ne e^{t^3}$, in fact $g'(x)=e^{x^3}$.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding of the theorem and not a typo. Confusing myself as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. Now, since$$g'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^{3n}}{n!}$$and since $g(0)=0$, you have$$g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)n!}.$$

Comment: Why is g(0)=0 mentioned explicitly? Is it necessary for the answer or enlightening?

Comment: It is essential. If, say, $g(x)=\int_{-1}^xe^{t^3}\,\mathrm dt$, then the answer would be$$\int_{-1}^0e^{t^3}\,\mathrm dt+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)n!},$$since $g(0)=\int_{-1}^0e^{t^3}\,\mathrm dt$.